# Plotting a simple chart on Python Or R with X-Value(AGE), and Y-VALUES(HEIGHT and WEIGHT)

Tags: python, r

How can I plot a simple chart where the x-axis is AGE and the Y-axis(values) are HEIGHT and WEIGHT from a file called 'data-file-2022'?

file only has these 3 columns all integers , 'age' age of the person, 'height' height in nearest CMs and 'weight' weight in nearest KGs

I want to have x-axis as age, while plotting the height and weight as CHART.

Comment: What's the format and schema of the file?

Comment: the file is actually just these 3 columns, age of the person in integers, height in CMs and Weight in KGs

Comment: Is it a CSV? Can you post the first few rows of the data?

Comment: age;height;weight
34;184;83
17;172;78
45;168;65
19;188;88

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the matplotlib library, I assume you either want a line or a scatter chart.

### Line chart:

###### Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

age = [34,17,45,19]
height = [184,172,168,188]
weight = [83,78,65,88]
age, height, weight = zip(*sorted(zip(age, height, weight)))

mpl.plot(age,height)
mpl.plot(age,weight)
mpl.show()
```

###### [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtW6P.png)

### Scatter chart:

###### Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

age = [34,17,45,19]
height = [184,172,168,188]
weight = [83,78,65,88]

mpl.scatter(age,height)
mpl.scatter(age,weight)
mpl.show()
```

###### [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptiuU.png)

You have to convert your file into lists but without knowing more about your file I can't help you further.

Comment: this is the first couple of rows 

age;height;weight 34;184;83 17;172;78 45;168;65 19;188;88 

I have 2 different fields I want to plot (height and weight) with x-axis being the age as. line chart like you showed

thankss

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: thank you so much, I will chew on this a little, try to import my file directly instead of the variables and such, much appreciated